# Integrated Login Form Going in circles

Tags: php, html, forms, integration

So I am building this domain on a seperate URL for right now, but that shouldnt effect a login coding.  Everytime I click "login" it just cycles the current page.

Here is my code

What Am I missing or doing wrong?  Reset Password works perfect.

Thanks,

Jeff Gray

Comment: where there is no action on your form?

Comment: You dont have the page name in Action.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "it just cycles the current page"? I went to link and I didn't see anything odd.

Comment: page name? Sorry, my brain is past overload. lol

Comment: Are you doing the validation on the same page? http://exoticdipz.jeffpgray.com/order.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the `action` attribute in the form. If you submit a form without an action attribute, or an empty value for the action attribute, the form's action becomes the current page (also known in PHP as `PHP_SELF`)

```
<form  action="PAGE_WHERE_IT_IS_SUPPOSED_TO_GO" ...>

</form>
```

If, by chance the form is supposed to have the same `action` as the current page, then the code provided above is not sufficient enough to handle the request; as you would need to parse the form (above any HTML output), complete your server time validation, and determine if you needed to keep them on the same page (insufficient/incomplete data) or redirect the user to the next stage of your site.

Comment: When action is not defined the form post itself to the same page. Maybe that's what he wants

Comment: bahhhhh, you guys are on the ball, appreciate that.... and no its a "box billing" software install... and its suppose to login the user.. but it just keeps circling.. fixed that with action (stupid me mistake and overlook), and now says you need to login :/

Comment: i normally dont have this issue, but this is the first box billing install I have done, and it seems like something wierd within it.

Comment: I can't say what's in the system that you have. I can only try to help you get to that system.